# NEXT JS TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/projects OR Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: javascript, mongoose, next.js

im using

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
```

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
```

and access to my api (pages/api/proyects/)created with next js in my local host

```
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/projects");
```

when i build the app in netlify i get this error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
So i try to change the url just to "/api/projects/"

```
  const res = await fetch("/api/projects/");
```

but i get a new error "TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/project" so thats say that next js needs a complete url to access to the data,

my final URL in netlify is https://v2ds.netlify.app, so i think that i need first my api running, but how i gonna do it if to get my api running i need to deploy my app?

"netlify wants this:"

```
const res = await fetch("https://v2ds.netlify.app/api/projects/");
```

but how i acces to the api if the application has not been built for the first time?
im working with getStaticProps, getStaticPaths mongoose and the API by next js

so the final question is how i deploy my app to netlify and access to the data in build moment?

thanks,
wish you can help me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the solution is: first deploy your app with only the api (with no pages, just the api) so when in build time when your app needs the data can access to the public link!;
later build the entire app and it going to work!

Comment: Both Answer and question is given by you

Answer (score 10):

in server side, everything is on the server. So you do not need to make http request for relative url, you just need to import your api file and then run this,

```
 const res = await import("../../..the location of your api file");
```

then you can access to your handler function like:

```
await (await res.handler()).json()
```

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by separating api request base URL, according to the running environment. For ex.

let's create an component called checkEnvironment and then just return base URL from the component.

```
export const checkEnvironment = () => {
  let base_url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://example.com"; // https://v2ds.netlify.app

  return base_url;
};
```

and then just use this in your getStaticProps like this :

```
export const getStaticProps = async (ctx: any) => {
    const posts = await fetch(checkEnvironment().concat("/api/posts"));
    const json = await posts.json();
  
    return {
      props: { data: json },
    };
};
```

**Edit**-
You can also do something like this for your local and production environment:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const request = await fetch(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? `http://${ctx.req?.headers.host}/api/products`
      : `https://${ctx.req?.headers.host}/api/products`
  );
  const json = await request.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data: json.data,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how i gonna ask to example.com "or my final url" if i dont have deployed my app yet, im trying to deploy it but when im in build time i cant get the data from my next js api! becouse it cant be in my localhost or final url or temporal url

Comment: Okay, I am editing my answer to make it easier for you to understand, and it is working perfectly fine on Netlify as well.

Answer (score -3):

Check if your mongod terminal are properly connected with mongosh database.